# Sovling an improper integral in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

**Problem:** We are given that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function defined by$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4+1}.
$$
Solve the improper integral

$$I = \iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(x,y) \,\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y}{x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4+1}.$$

I am not sure on how I should approach this. Is there anyway to simplify this so it is easier to solve?

Comment: $x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4=r^4$. Maybe contour integration ensues.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco oh wow,i'm so blind. Thank you so much :D

Comment: Polar coordinates.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Is this correct? "Check the new answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is what i've done so far:

$$f(z)dz=\int^R_{-R}f(z)dz +\int_{\gamma R}f(z)dz$$

where $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4+1}$$

Comment: @AlexFrancisco the boundaries still remains $[\infty, -\infty]$ right?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Okey, I got this now. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco okey I had to read a little bit about contour integrals . But my final answer is $\int\int_{R^2}f(x,y)dxdy=\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: OK, I overlooked something. Actually,$$\int_0^{+∞}\frac r{r^4+1}\,\mathrm dr=\frac12\int_0^{+∞}\frac{\mathrm d(r^2)}{r^4+1}=\frac12\arctan r^2\Biggr|_0^{+∞}=\frac π4.$$

Comment: @AlexFrancisco How?

Comment: Shouldn't it also be $\int^{2\pi}_{0}(\frac{\pi}{4})d\theta$ why is the radius going from $+\infty$ to $0$? @AlexFrancisco